# canPerformAction:with sender method called on tap in ios 9

Tags: ios, uibutton, uimenucontroller, uiresponder

one thing I observed in iOS 9.0 is that when I tap on button or TableView, `canPerformMethod:withSender:` method is called with sender as UIButton type. I am using this method to prepare my customized option menu.

I did not observed that in previous iOS. Can anyone see me API changes, because I went through overall changes of iOS, but I did not find above mentioned changes in change log or change history.

Answer (score 0):

Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canPerformAction:withSender:),

> iOS 3.0 introduced system capabilities for generating motion events,
>   specifically the motion of shaking the device. The event-handling
>   methods for these kinds of events are motionBegan:withEvent:,
>   motionEnded:withEvent:, and motionCancelled:withEvent:. Additionally
>   for iOS 3.0, the canPerformAction:withSender: method allows responders
>   to validate commands in the user interface while the undoManager
>   property returns the nearest NSUndoManager object in the responder
>   chain.

So, all the `UIResponder` sub classes are entitled to receive a call back for `canPerformAction:withSender:`. You should use `sender` parameter to do the handling in this method.

[image]

Comment: Abinav, I checked the doc and I completely agree that every element which is inherited from UIResponder class will execute `canPerformAction` method. Then I checked my code, this method is not hitting in previous iOS. Can you check that.?

Comment: Because what I am observing currently is when I click on button or TableView, `canPerformAction:withSender:` method hits.